Are packages such as PIL, Holidays, and Rich compatible at all with Mojo?
I am interested in Mojo and would ideally like to update my command line calendaring app from Python to Mojo. I'm not as interested in the performance optimization as I am features such as binary creation for varying platforms. Ideally, I would like to distribute my program utilizing libraries such as PIL, Holidays, and Rich to other systems without them needing to have Python configured.
What is the current state of compatibility? Is this feasible, not feasible? Is this on the roadmap at all? I understand that Mojo is a superset of Python aimed primarily at machine learning workloads, but I hoped that the benefits would spill over for other use cases.
